# Meaning of "for while knowledge"

Tags: phrase-meaning, sentence-meaning

> We will not [says Socrates] then allow our charges, whom we
>   expect to prove good men, being men, to play the parts of
>   women and imitate a woman young or old wrangling with
>   her husband, defying heaven, loudly boasting, fortunate in
>   her own conceit, or involved in misfortune and possessed by
>   grief and lamentation – still less a woman that is sick, in
>   love, or in labor . . . Nor may they imitate slaves, female and
>   male, doing the offices of slaves . . . Nor yet, as it seems, bad
>   men who are cowards and who do the opposite of the things
>   we just now spoke of [things done by men who are “brave,
>   sober, pious, free”], reviling and lampooning one another,
>   speaking foul words in their cups or when sober and in other
>   ways sinning against themselves and others in word and
>   deed after the fashion of such men. And I take it they must
>   not form the habit of likening themselves to madmen either
>   in words nor yet in deeds. **For while knowledge** they must
>   have both of mad and bad men and women, they must do
>   and imitate nothing of this kind . . . Are they to imitate smiths
>   and other craftsmen or the rowers of triremes and those
>   who call the time to them or other things connected
>   therewith?

I haven't got any idea about the meaning of "for while knowledge" this structure is new for me.

This passage is from the book named: On literature.

Comment: It's like "yoda speak".  "knowledge they have" just means "they have knowledge".   "Begun have these Clone Wars!"  Just means "The Clone Wars have begun."

Answer (score 7):

> *For while knowledge they must have both of mad and bad men and women, they must do and imitate nothing of this kind...*

...is (clumsy, imho<sup>1</sup>) resequencing and circumlocutory phrasing of the more easily understood...

> *For while **they must have knowledge of both** mad and bad men and women, they must **not do or imitate anything like this**...*

Here "for while" could be replaced more casually with "because even though".

---

<sup>1</sup> In all fairness, I should point out that it's a *translation* (from [almost a century ago](https://www.google.com/search?biw=1341&bih=775&tbs=cdr%3A1%2Ccd_min%3A1%2F1%2F1800%2Ccd_max%3A12%2F31%2F1950&tbm=bks&ei=_youXMzENa3IrgSwk4vgAQ&q=%22the+habit+of+likening+themselves+to+madmen+either%22&oq=%22the+habit+of+likening+themselves+to+madmen+either%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3...23921.26184.0.33557.2.2.0.0.0.0.294.412.0j1j1.2.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..0.0.0....0.TKcyboTDMQY)), which may even reflect the original ancient Greek construction. But I wouldn't expect any "modern" translation to include such roundabout phrasing.

---

As regards the "introductory" element ***For while*** - the first point to make is that this is an *entirely* optional component. Within which ***while*** can be understood as meaning ***although***...

> ***Although*** they must do this, they must not do that
>    ...equivalent to...
>    *They must do this, **but** they must not do that*

As a general rule of thumb I think the second version is to be preferred - to me at least, it seems easier to parse (but this is a *very* fine point of style).

And the initial word ***For*** is really just another somewhat outdated "stylistic flourish" (but in principle it could be understood as meaning ***because*** - referring to and explaining the preceding sentence). If you look at older versions of the Bible, for example, you'll find quite a lot of sentences that start with ***For*** for no obvious reason. It doesn't really "mean" anything at all.

Comment: Happy New Year, my friend!

Comment: Likewise, [me old mucker!](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22me+old+mucker%22) :)

Comment: Lots of Thanks. But I don't get the meaning of " for while"

Comment: is it better to write: for, while they must have...

Comment: @ViserHashemi - yes, you're correct.  The passage you quoted sounds stupid.  Your phrasing is correct.

Comment: @ViserHashemi: Good point. I'll edit to cover that aspect...

Comment: I would say "for while" is more "because although" than just "although.

Comment: @Muzer: As pointed out by Tashus's earlier edit to my question, which I only noticed after making my own edit to address the point. But I'm sticking to my guns - the word ***for*** wouldn't so likely be included today, and to a first approximation, it's a "meaningless stylistic flourish".